# _.extend doesn't shallow copy elements to destination properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've just started to write a Backbone library which goes like this,

```
(function() {
    var root = this;

    if(root && !root.Backbone) {
        console.log('BackboneJS does not exist!.');
    } else {
        Backbone = root.Backbone;
    }

    var Form = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'submit': function(event) {
                this.trigger('submit', event);
            }
        },
        initialize: function(options) {
            var self = this;
            var options = this.options = _.extend(options, {
                submitButton: false
            });
        }
    });
    Backbone.Form = Form;
})();
```

And I'm invoking this through jQuery (in my index.html) like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myForm = new Backbone.Form({
  options: {
    hasTopButtons : true,
    hasEdit: false,
    hasPrint: true
  }
});
```

But, when I use the `_.extend` function to shallow copy additional keys to the `options` it doesn't seems to me including the new key into the existing `options` array, instead it creates a new one outside of the `options` array like this,

[image: What is currently happening]

Instead of the below structure.

[image: How I expect that to come]

Can someone help me to find out what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking the function incorrectly. You want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var myForm = new Backbone.Form({
    hasTopButtons : true,
    hasEdit: false,
    hasPrint: true
  });
});
```

Your code explicitly passes an object that has a single property called "options".

Also, in your "initialize" function, there's a spurious `var` declaration:

```
        var options = this.options = _.extend(options, {
            submitButton: false
        });
```

That should *probably* be

```
        this.options = _.extend({}, options, {
            submitButton: false
        });
```

The `_.extend` function modifies the first object, and you probably don't want to be messing with client objects like that. Thus, you can pass in a new empty object, and `_.extend()` will shallow-copy all the client properties into it.

Comment: My bad!. You're spot on @Pointy!.. :-)